# avconv - drawtext - apply filter for given time period

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, avconv

I am on Ubuntu 15.10 (wily). I want to add a text to the video for the 1st 30sec. I can add video to the entire length of the video by using the following command

```
$ avconv -i input.MTS -metadata title="my video" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf:text='My Text':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=60:fontsize=36" -strict experimental out.mp4
```

With `ffmpeg` there is an option `drawtext=enable=between(t,0,30)` but with `avconv` this is not a valid option.

```
 $ avconv -i 00054.MTS -metadata title="my video" -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,0,30)':fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf:text='My Text':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=60:fontsize=36" -strict experimental out.mp4

 drawtext @ 0x18b8d20] No such option: enable.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x18c3000] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'enable=between(t,0,30):fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf:text=My Text:fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=60:fontsize=36'
```

With `avconv` how can I add a text to the video for a given time period?

```
$ avconv --version
avconv version 11.4-6:11.4-2ubuntu3, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 11 2015 07:00:13 with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-15ubuntu1) 20150808
```

Answer (score 1):

`avconv` does not have the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing). Use `ffmpeg` instead: it has more features, development is very active, and `avconv` is eventually going to be removed from Ubuntu anyway.

The real `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg has returned to Ubuntu in 15.04, so just install it from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Here is a work around for the missing enable= in avconv. Use the draw parameter like draw='lte(t,10)' this will draw the text from start till 10sec. (( alternatively you can use draw='lte(n,10)' this will draw for 10 frames. )) 
Eg:

```
$ avconv -i inputfile.MTS -metadata title="my video" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf:text='My Text:fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=60:fontsize=36:draw='lte(t,5)'" -strict experimental out.mp4
```